# Default value not being respected in devcontainer.json remoteEnv when using Docker Volume

Tags: docker-volume, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I'm somewhat "cheating" in that I opened up a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8963) for this but am hoping to get a hit here on SO :)

I'm using VS Code devcontainers and cloning a repo into a docker/dev volume. I set up my *devcontainer.json* to pass a (possibly empty) environment variable from the local environment to the container via `remoteEnv`. I set a default value, e.g.

```json
{
  "remoteEnv": {
    "CONTAINER_VAR": "${localEnv:LOCAL_VAR:default_value}"
  }
}
```

However, in my container, that environment variable ends up being empty (i.e. the default value is not used). If I run the same exact devcontainer but associate it with my local filesystem (i.e. don't use a Docker volume), it works as expected.

### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create devcontainer by cloning a repo into a container volume
2. Setup remoteEnv to pass in a local environment variable with a default value
3. Make sure local environment is empty
4. Check container's environment variable

Logs and more details in the linked issue above.